# How do I filter an array with TypeScript in Angular 2?

Tags: arrays, filter, typescript, angular

ng-2 parent-child data inheritance has been a difficulty for me.

What seems that could be a fine working practical solution is filtering my total array of data to an array consisting of only child data referenced by a single parent id.
In other words: data-inheritance becomes data filtering by one parent id.

In a concrete example this can look like: filtering a books array to only show the books with a certain `store_id`.

```ts
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';

export class Store {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export class Book {
  id: number;
  shop_id: number;
  title: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'book',
  template:`
    <p>These books should have a label of the shop: {{shop.id}}:</p>

    <p *ngFor="#book of booksByShopID">{{book.title}}</p>
  `
])
export class BookComponent {
  @Input()
  store: Store;

  public books = BOOKS;

  // "Error: books is not defined"
  // ( also doesn't work when books.filter is called like: this.books.filter
  // "Error: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined" )
  var booksByStoreID = books.filter(book => book.store_id === this.store.id)
}

var BOOKS: Book[] = [
  { 'id': 1, 'store_id': 1, 'name': 'Dichtertje' },
  { 'id': 2, 'store_id': 1, 'name': 'De uitvreter' },
  { 'id': 3, 'store_id': 2, 'name': 'Titaantjes' }
];
```

TypeScript is new to me, but I think I am close to making things work here.

(Also overwriting the original books array could be an option, then using `*ngFor="#book of books"`.)

**EDIT**
Getting closer, but still giving an error.

```ts
//changes on top:
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

// ..omitted

//changed component:
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() 
  store: Store;

  public books = BOOKS;

  // adding the data in a constructor needed for ngInit
  // "EXCEPTION: No provider for Array!"
  constructor(
    booksByStoreID: Book[];
  ) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.booksByStoreID = this.books.filter(
      book => book.store_id === this.store.id);
  }
}

// ..omitted
```

Answer (score 264, accepted):

You need to put your code into `ngOnInit` and use the `this` keyword:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.booksByStoreID = this.books.filter(
          book => book.store_id === this.store.id);
}
```

You need `ngOnInit` because the input `store` wouldn't be set into the constructor:

> **ngOnInit** is called right after the directive's data-bound properties have been checked for the first time, and before any of its children have been checked. It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

(https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnInit-interface.html)

In your code, the books filtering is directly defined into the class content...

Comment: Makes sense. I get the error "Error: ngOnInit is not defined" after adding your piece of code, importing `OnInit` and adding `booksByStoreID = Book[];` in the component.

Comment: I think that it's rather: `booksByStoreID: Book[];`

Comment: Doesn't work either. Should I puts this in a constructor maybe? I tried this, then I get an error complaining about the `]`

Comment: Could you add in your question (in an edit paragraph for example) the code your tried? It's difficult for me to guess what you tried ;-) Thanks!

Comment: I seem to get a DI Exception, while before buidling the data filtering retrieving the store id wasn't a problem at all and printed in the template. Maybe you can find something I overlooked in my edit?

Comment: It's because you should use this: `booksByAimID: Book[];
constructor() {}`. ``booksByAimID: Book[];` is a property declaration not a constructor parameter. Angular2 leverages constructor parameter for dependency injection...

Comment: Thanks! The filtering completly works :) A new issue arose though. When clicking in the parent component such that another store is selected, the old store_id remains and the list of books stay the same...

Comment: Great! You need to implement `ngOnChanges` to detect this. When `store_id` will be updated, this method will be called and you can execute the same thing than `ngOnInit`...

Comment: `ngOnChanges(store) { this.store.id = store[id].currentValue };` leaves me with a "RefferenceError". Any idea?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do ;-) I thought of this: `ngOnChanges() {
  this.booksByStoreID = this.books.filter(
          book => book.store_id === this.store.id);
}`

Comment: Thanks, my app is functional :) I thought I could overwrite the input values since ngOnInit will be called after ngOnChanges. But maybe I misunderstood and this is the only way.

Comment: when I try this solution showing as " Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"

Comment: in my case 'books' is an array and I need output also a array

Comment: Can we put an OR (||) condition here like (book => book.store_id === 2|| book.store_id === 5) ?

Answer (score 24):

You can check an example in Plunker over here [plunker example filters](http://plnkr.co/edit/cO8b9JO7k9kNxF6Qr4lS?p=preview)

```
filter() {

    let storeId = 1;
    this.bookFilteredList = this.bookList
                                .filter((book: Book) => book.storeId === storeId);
    this.bookList = this.bookFilteredList; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To filter an array irrespective of the property type (i.e. for all property types), we can create a custom filter pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: "filter" })
export class ManualFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(itemList: any, searchKeyword: string) {
    if (!itemList)
      return [];
    if (!searchKeyword)
      return itemList;
    let filteredList = [];
    if (itemList.length > 0) {
      searchKeyword = searchKeyword.toLowerCase();
      itemList.forEach(item => {
        //Object.values(item) => gives the list of all the property values of the 'item' object
        let propValueList = Object.values(item);
        for(let i=0;i<propValueList.length;i++)
        {
          if (propValueList[i]) {
            if (propValueList[i].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchKeyword) > -1)
            {
              filteredList.push(item);
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return filteredList;
  }
}

//Usage

//<tr *ngFor="let company of companyList | filter: searchKeyword"></tr>
```

Don't forget to import the pipe in the app module

*We might need to customize the logic to filer with dates.*