# Filter elements of array if contained in other

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have two arrays like below format,

```
this.originalArray = [{
    id: 10,
    name: 'a',
    roleInfo: [{
        roleID: 5,
        roleName: 'USER'
    }]
},
{
    id: 20,
    name: 'b',
    roleInfo: [{
        roleID: 5,
        roleName: 'Admin',
    }]
 },
 {
     id: 30,
     name: 'c',
     roleInfo: [{
         roleID: 5,
         roleName: 'Support',
     }]
 }]

this.removeElements =      
    roleInfo: [{
        roleID: 5,
        roleName: 'Support',        
}]
```

Question: How to filter the originalArray that are not there in the removeElements arrays

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I filter an array with TypeScript in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003551/how-do-i-filter-an-array-with-typescript-in-angular-2)

Comment: Try something and come back with a concrete question/problem

Comment: @Jota.Toledo   I need to filter the array, of different array

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var reuslt =  originalArray.filter(item => removeElements.find(test => test.id == item.id));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
originalArray.filter(item => removeElements.some(f => f.id == item.id));
```

Answer (score -1):

this works in (almost) all browsers.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var b = [2, 3];

var result = [], found;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    found = false;
    // find a[i] in b
    for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        if (a[i] == b[j]) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        result.push(a[i]);
    }
}
```

or if compatibility is not an issue

a.filter(i => b.some(j => j.id === i.id));

Answer (score -1):

```
this.originalArray =[ { id: 10, name: 'a', roleInfo: [{ roleID: 5, roleName: 'USER' }] },
  { id: 20, name: 'b', roleInfo: [{ roleID: 5, roleName: 'Admin', }] },
   { id: 30, name: 'c', roleInfo: [{ roleID: 5, roleName: 'Support', }] }, ]

   this.removeElements =[
    {
        id: 30,
        name: 'c',
        roleInfo: [{
            roleID: 5,
            roleName: 'Support',
        }]
    }]  

    var finalArr = [];
   this.originalArray.forEach(function(d){
   var filterArr =  this.removeElements.filter(function(d1){
      if(d1.id == d.id && d1.name == d.name){
        return d1;
      }
    });
    if(filterArr.length == 0){
      finalArr.push(d);
    }
   })
```