# Filter an array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Question:
 How can I display a pre selected item from my dropdown just based on it's ID.

Explanation/Problem: 
My dropdown options are from a dynamic web service that finds me Providers based on a users ZipCode. An example of a Provider is {Phone: "5093240817", sp_id: "1", Name: "John Doe" … }... The dropdown displays the name for the user to pick but we only store the ID. So the **Problem** that I am facing is if the user returns to change their provider, I want to display the users original Providers Name, but I only have the ID.

Sidenote: we can't store the value of Name because the web service can change the providers name value.

My Attempt: 
My idea to solve this was to "filter" the array of Providers based on the original ID and then find the name that way. I'm new to Angular and typescript so i'm having trouble...

My idea.

 I was reading another SO post and trying to understand how they do this, but again i'm just having trouble. ([How do I filter an array with TypeScript in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003551/how-do-i-filter-an-array-with-typescript-in-angular-2))

```
    const showValue = this.serviceProvider.filter(sp_id => 
    this.selectedAppointment.sp_id)
```

**this.selectedAppointment.sp_id hold the original ID value.

Service Providers Options 
 
{Phone: "5093240817", sp_id: "1", Longitude: -77.3841197, Provider Type: "Pediatric", Latitude: 38.9808589,Name: "John Doe" …}
1

{Phone: "097420454", sp_id: "3", Longitude: -77.3898602, Provider Type: "Pediatric", Latitude: 38.914697200000006, Name: "Kim" …}
2

Answer (score 1):

In your example `sp_id` is the service provider option being passed to each iteration of the `filter` callback. I think you may be misunderstanding how *Arrow functions* work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Also, look at the `filter` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

I think what you want to do is this (which would compare the `sp_id` of the option to the selected value):

```
 this.serviceProvider.filter(sp => sp.sp_id === this.selectedAppointment.sp_id);
```

Or, to provide some clarity:

```
this.serviceProvider.filter((serviceProvider) => {
    return serviceProvider.sp_id === this.selectedAppointment.sp_id;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. We ended up going another route to set the provider. This was very informal though which is what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this issue by iterating through the options and then setting the matching value in the form!

```
  setProvider(sp_id) {
    for(let sp in this.serviceProvider) {
      if (sp_id == this.serviceProvider[sp].sp_id) {
        (<FormGroup>this.patientAppointmentForm)
          .patchValue({serviceProvider: 
this.serviceProvider[sp].sp_id}, {onlySelf: true});
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Don't use `==`, always use `===`.  Further, why do you need to iterate over this? Based on what I'm seeing, seems like it could simply be `.patchValue( { serviceProvider: sp_id}, { onlySelf: true})` - without the loop.

Comment: The value of serviceProvider sp_id is a number. We need to iterate through all of the of the service_providers and find the one that has the matching sp_id so we can find the name. To clarify, our database only stores the ID from the service provider.. We need to use the ID from our database to find the name from the web service.