# How to filter an object array in typescript

Tags: angular, filter, autocomplete, angular-material

I implement an input field with auto complete function, which uses material auto complete. 
now I have a question, how I can filter a object array in typescript.

this object array contains key and value.

the html looks like this:

```html
<input matInput type="text" [formControl]="locationField" [(ngModel)]="node.field" [name]="node.id"
             [matAutocomplete]="auto" placeholder="Field"/>
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let field of fields" [value]="field.key">
        {{field.value}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

now I need a mehtod, which creats new mat-option, if I tipp new values in input field.

the filter funciton looks like this:

```
private filterField(value: string): string[] {
    const allFields = this.locationFilterFields;
    if (value) {
        this.locationFieldResults = ArrayObject.filter((result) => {
            return searchFieldResult.indexOf(value) !== -1;
        });
    }
}
```

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't know the type of **value** you are having but this is how you can filter array of objects:-

```
var friends= [
   {name: "rachel", drink: "latte"},
   {name: "joey", drink: "latte"},
   {name: "phoebe", drink: "tea"},
   {name: "chandler", drink: "tea"}
];

   var newFriends=  heroes.filter(function(hero) {
   return friends.drink== "latte";
});
```

Comment: Maybe review before you post, there's multiple issues with your answer

Comment: @ShannonHochkins add answer yourself, than just writing a comment. I'll review your answer.

Comment: I have just done so

Answer (score 0):

```html
    Object.keys(array_object).filter(key => typeof array_object[key as any] === "number").forEach((tempobjentry)=> {
//      inspect tempobjentry
    });
```

Above code snippet filters array_object entries whose key type is a number and forEach helps to enumerate through filtered entries. You can replace the condition to suit your requirement. Hope this helps. Also refer to [How do I filter an array with TypeScript in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003551/how-do-i-filter-an-array-with-typescript-in-angular-2) for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to filter the array based on a specific key, you can define your array of objects similar to @himanshu above, the difference being the filter will return with the correct types.

After running the filter function, if you try to do something with the drink of 'tea', typescript will let you know that tea is not comparable to latte if that's what you're filtering on.

```
type Drink = 'latte' | 'tea';
interface Friend {
  name: string;
  drink: Drink;
}
const friends: Friend[] = [
  { name: "rachel", drink: "latte" },
  { name: "joey", drink: "latte" },
  { name: "phoebe", drink: "tea" },
  { name: "chandler", drink: "tea" }
];

function filterByType<T extends Drink>(friends: Friend[], type: T): Array<Friend & {
  drink: T
}> {
  return friends.filter((friend): friend is Friend & {
    drink: T
  } => friend.drink === type);
}

const newFriends = filterByType(friends, 'latte');

newFriends.forEach(newFriend => {
  switch (newFriend.drink) {
    case 'latte':
      // is available
      break;
    case 'tea':
       // Type '"tea"' is not comparable to type '"latte"'
    break;
  }
});
```